# PhpStorm - working on a remote server

Tags: phpstorm, remote-server

I have never used PhpStorm before for remote development because I used to work locally.

I am wondering if there is a method to set PhpStorm to work in such a way so it will be identical, in terms of functionality, to local development?
At least, debugging and jumping to functions/variables declaration across the whole project?

Tried to google it but found nothing. Maybe someone knows?

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials -- check debugging and deployment parts. In any case: for debugging you still need local copy of your files, at least those that will be executed/debugged.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to work with remote server development :

- With a physically server
- With a Virtual Machine locally

Those 2 ways are identical workflow parameters for working with this.

In PHPStorm the main area for parameters workflow deployement on remote server is : *PHPStorm > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployement > Deployement*

In this area you config the connection on your remote server (you before must config access on your remote server). **SFTP** is the best way to use this connection.

Most important to select where you want to send/push your modified code with *Root path*. Upload manually or use the sync auto functionality of PHPStorm use this parameter.

Mappings tabs is not very important you can keep this without change except for '*Deployement path on server*' which just type '/' character if you have selected the good '*Root Path*' in tab before.

For starting you can forget the *Excluded Paths tab*. after if you work on symfony framework you use this to exclude the vendor directory.

Don't forget to set the options '*use as Default*' if you want to upload or sync auto more fastly and friendly.

Now you must parameters and config correctly your remote server for server be able to run the code which send it with PHPStorm. Dependly on your framework or other technologies you use.

Finally you have :

- PHPStorm config OK for send correctly your modification code (auto or manually)
- remote server config OK for executing and running correctly the code you are before sending from PHPStorm to your server remote

**WARNING :** you never run your website into your local OS.

**IMPORTANT :** config a web server on your remote server and don't forget to install layer for PHP executing script.